# Why doesn't CDC work via Integration Services Catalogs in SSMS while working via VS?

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, ssms

I've created an ETL process in SSIS project in VS2019. I used CDC in one of the projects. It works fine when I execute it in VS.
I deployed the solution to Integration Services Catalog in SSMS and when I execute it from there, I get the error which says that my CDC package can't run on the installed edition of Integration Services since it requires Enterprise Edition or higher.
Just trying to get my head around trying to figure out why it works in VS and throws an error in SSMS.

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-features-supported-by-the-editions-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#ISAT) confirms you need Enterprise for Change Data Capture components by Attunity, and that you don't for designing.

Comment: Thanks, this website says: The Change Data Capture components by Attunity require Enterprise edition. The Change Data Capture Service and the Change Data Capture Designer, however, do not require Enterprise edition. You can use the Designer and the Service on a computer where SSIS is not installed. Does it mean that if I change my package so that it won't use CDC components but functions and stored procedure, I'll still be able to use CDC when I download it to SSIS folder?